# Publish Angular library to private Verdaccio npm repository

Tags: npm, verdaccio

I have a private `Verdaccio` npm repository.

I configured `authentification` for using htppasswd file

```
auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: /verdaccio/conf/htpasswd
    max_users: -1
```

So now nobody can do `npm add ...` but must use `npm login ...`

After being logged, I can publish my library with `npm publish`

But there are few point I don't understand :

- `npm login` is asking me an email.  But what's the point ?  I don't find any trace of that email in the published package.
- After `npm login` a token is generated in my .npmrc file.  Does it have a validity date ?
- After being published, in Verdaccio, I see anonymous as `author name`. The only solution I found to 'put' my name is adding an author tag in the `package.json`.  But if we are 3 persons working on that library we have to change our name each time ?  Is there a way to associate (on the server) an htpasswdd with a author name/email ?

Answer (score 1):

here Verdaccio core maintainer. I'll try to answer all your questions.

> npm login is asking me an email. But what's the point ? I don't find any trace of that email in the published package.

**Verdaccio does not requires email**, but unfortunately `npmjs.org` does, so just write any value and skip that step, we cannot do anything to avoid that.

> After npm login a token is generated in my .npmrc file. Does it have a validity date ?

That depends of which auth you are using, by default the token never expires using

```
auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: /verdaccio/conf/htpasswd
```

but if you want to expire tokens then you would need to add the [security new property introduced in Verdaccio 4](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/configuration#security).

```
security:
  api:
    jwt:
      sign:
        expiresIn: 29d
```

The example above will expire all tokens after 29 days and it overrides the default behaviour, the tokens becomes compatible with JWT compatible and share all it properties and benefits.

> After being published, in Verdaccio, I see anonymous as author name. The only solution I found to 'put' my name is adding an author tag in the package.json. But if we are 3 persons working on that library we have to change our name each time ? Is there a way to associate (on the server) an htpasswdd with a author name/email ?

Author can be only one, but you have more options, either **contributors** or **maintainers**. Just add them in the `package.json` as follows.

[image]

The result would be this in the Verdaccio UI.

[image]